# react scroll with styled component is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using react with styled component and react-scroll to create a simple menu.
I want to make a one-page application. Everything is fine but when I scroll to a specific section of my page, it should show me the tab has been activated on my Nav. but it doesnt work at all.

```
<Nav>
        <NavBarCotainer>
          <NavMenu>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                to="about"
              >
                About Us
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </NavMenu>
        </NavBarCotainer>
      </Nav>
```

and in my styled component, I have

```
export const NavLink = styled(LinkS)`
  color: blue;
  &:active {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

this work when I click on any of the links it quickly changes to red but becomes blue again and when I visit that section it wont turn red at all.

if I change that to:

```
  &.active {
    color: red;
  }

import { Link as LinkS } from "react-scroll";
```

it wont do anything at all, when I visit a section of page it will be always blue.

How can I fix this issue, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use radium module for pseudo css implementation.

```
import Radium from 'radium'

const style = {
  color: 'blue',
  ':active': {
    color: 'red'
  }
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Nav>
    <NavBarCotainer>
      <NavMenu>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            to="about"
            style={style}
          >
            About Us
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      </NavMenu>
    </NavBarCotainer>
  </Nav>
  );
};

const MyStyledComponent = Radium(MyComponent);
```